# How to save WmiObject -Class win32_logialdisk or others WmiIbjects in a PowerShell array and save in CSV

Tags: powershell, automation, export-to-csv

I try to extract the values of `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LocalDisk` on a CSV file but I get on the CSV instead of the values only get`SystemObject[]`.

The stat3.csv fie contains:

```
"#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject,
"Disk"
"10.10.0.177","System.Object[]"
```

How Can I get the values instead of the `System.Object[]` string?

```
  $list = gc D:\Foo\script\bahh.txt 

  foreach ($line in $list) {

    $creds = get-credential
    echo $IP
    $creds = Get-Credential
    $disk = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $IP |
            ft DeviceID, @{Name="Free Disk Space (GB)";e={$_.FreeSpace /1GB}},
              @{Name="Total Disk Size (GB)";e={$_.Size /1GB}} -AutoSize

     $data | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name Disk -Value $disk

     $data | Export-Csv "D:\Foo\script\stat3.csv" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace `Format-Table` with `Select-Object`. Also, don't cram multiple disks into one line. `Get-WmiObject ... | Select-Object PSComputerName, DeviceId, Size, Freespace | Export-Csv ... -NoType`

Comment: Thankyou @AnsgarWiechers in regard to Selec-Object that worked fine but on the CSV file I only get System.Object[]  but the values are got correctly becasue I do a Write-Host and Got the values as: @{DeviceID=A:; Free Disk Space (GB)=0; Total Disk Size (GB)=0} @{DeviceID=C:; Free Disk Space (GB)=7.58526229858398; Total Disk Size (GB)=59.4833908081055} @{DeviceID=D:; Free Disk Space (GB)=646
.496948242188; Total Disk Size (GB)=2047.8730430603} @{DeviceID=E:; Free Disk Space (GB)=0; Total Disk Size (GB)=0}

Comment: While your output clearly tells me that you didn't do what I told you to do, it doesn't tell me what you actually *did*. Please [edit] your question and show your updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a simple list of IP addresses or computer names in your file `bahh.txt` you could do something like this:

```
$list = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Foo\script\bahh.txt'

$Results = foreach($IP in $list){
   $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $IP
   $CmpSstm = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $IP
   foreach($disk in $Disks){ 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'IP Address' = $IP
            'DeviceID' = $disk.DeviceID
            'Free Disk Space (GB)' = $disk.FreeSpace/1GB
            'Total Disk Size (GB)' = $disk.Size/1GB
            'Physical Processors' = $CmpSstm.NumberofProcessors
            'Logical Processors' = $CmpSstm.maxclockspeed
            'TotalPhysicalMemory (GB)' = [math]::truncate($CmpSstm.TotalPhysicalMemory /1GB)
        }
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path  'D:\Foo\script\stat3.csv'
```

Comment: I would like to still use the variable data because I need to put more data inside like     prc = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $IP | Select-Object  @{Name="Physical Processors";e={$_.NumberofProcessors}} ,@{Name="Logical Processors";e={$_.maxclockspeed}} , @{Name="TotalPhysicalMemory (GB)";e={[math]::truncate($_.TotalPhysicalMemory /1GB)}}

Comment: Of course you're free to extend my example with whatever you need. See the updated code. I'm sure you're now able to step further by yourself.  ;-)